# How do I compare different regression models?

Tags: multiple-regression, lasso, error, model-comparison

I have some data and after doing both LASSO and least squares estimation (the usual multiple linear regression) on the data I want to compare the performance of these models. If I compare the squared error, obviously least squares estimation will turn out to be better, because it is the model with minimum squared error.

Also, I know that LASSO introduces sparsity in the coefficients and hence gives more interpretability of the model, but how do I compare it with respect to the multiple linear regression. What kind of error should I compare in these two models to find out which is better?

Please help.

Comment: You should be testing out-of-sample. Train (estimate parameters) on part of your data set. Hold out some proportion (10% and 20% are common) of the data to use for testing. This mimics how a real machine learning model is used to make predictions based on data that were not used in model development (think of Siri doing speech recognition on a a child’s first sentence).

Comment: @Dave, can you please elaborate on how should I test exactly?

Comment: You have 1000 observations. Train your model on 800, selected randomly, and ignore the other 200. Once you have your parameter estimates, apply the regression to the remaining 200 points. Examine the predictions for accuracy, since you know the true observed y-values.

Comment: How did you do LASSO? Did you cross-validate to find the regularization parameter?

Comment: @Dave, that is a problem. I am struggling to do cross validation in R. There is no $cvpartition $ function in R like matlab.

Comment: I bet you can find a cross-validation function if you Google it (hint: caret package has a createFolds function) but you can code one yourself. That’s not a bad exercise, even if you want to use the established function in caret (or in Python’s sklearn).

Comment: Author, R caret package will help you

Comment: Why did you do this twice? What are your actual goals for your final model? What would "better" mean in your context?